# Generating word file with footer on each page in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I am using **jquery.wordexport.js** to export html to word file document dinamically. I need to put footer on each page with image. Can anyone help?

```
   $("#exportToWord").click(function(e) {
     prepareTable();
     body = window.data;
         if ($('#model_div').children().length > 0) {
             $('#model_div').empty();
         }
     if (window.success) {

         var content = "<div class='modal fade bs-example-modal-lg' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='myLargeModalLabel'><div class='modal-dialog modal-lg'><div class='modal-content'><div class='modal-body' id='model_body'><input type='button' onClick='exportWord()' value='Export' class='export_button'>" + body + "</div></div></div>";
         $('#model_div').append(content);
     };
 });

 function exportWord() {
     var name = $("#from").val().substring(0, 10) + ' ' + $("#to").val().substring(0, 10);
     $("#page-content").wordExport(name);
     $("#from").val(null);
     $("#to").val(null);
      window.success = false;
     window.data = null;

 }
```

**prepareTable()** function sets window.data to all data recieved from db using ajax. if successful window.success wil be true.

Comment: provide all relevant code. and show your own tries first

Comment: I have added my code @qiAlex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found jquery.googoose.js library from https://github.com/aadel112/googoose and now I'm generating well formatted Microsoft Word (.doc) file.

Comment: jquery.googoose.js library works with normal images but not works with images of base64 decoded. the base64 decoded images are not exporting to word

Comment: downloaded file doesn't print